# Unsticking div when it hits footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that sticks to the bottom of the screen and would like to unstick it once it hits footer. I get it to stick but once it scrolls down to footer it doesn't unstick.

```
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
var div = $('.floating-div');
var footer = $(document).outerHeight() - $('#footer').outerHeight() - div.outerHeight();


function stickyDiv() {


    if (scrollTop < footer) {
        div.addClass("sticky");

    }if (scrollTop >= footer) {
        div.removeClass("sticky");
        div.css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: footer + "px"
        });
    }
}


$(document).scroll(function () {
    stickyDiv();
});
```

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OpuLance/ce97999q/24/)

Comment: You can see in console https://jsfiddle.net/ce97999q/25/ that the condition to remove the sticky class is never met

Comment: Also `if (scrollTop >= footer)` could just be `else` since there is no other possible conditions. `scrollTop` should be set in the stickyDiv function because it changes every time you scroll

Comment: Just removing the fixed position would not look nice. You better leave the original and create new footer element to be sticky. When you come to bottom of page - hide it. This way you will avoid jumping on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do not use same element, but to clone the footer and add there new css class. That way you will avoid content jumping in time when you change the css `position` from fixed to relative or static and vice versa. It is also good for responsive design, because you have more control:

```js
var realFooter = $('.floating');
var floatingFooter = realFooter.clone().addClass('floating-div').appendTo( $('body') );

function stickyDiv() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var footerOffsetTop = realFooter.offset().top;
    if ((scrollTop+winHeight) > footerOffsetTop) {
        floatingFooter.fadeOut('fast');
    } else {
        floatingFooter.fadeIn('fast');
    }
}


$(document).scroll(function () {
    stickyDiv();
});
```

```css
.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:1000;
}
.floating {
    background: #ddd;
    height:100px;
}
.floating-div {
    background:#888;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#top {
    height:900px;
}
#wrapper {
    height:1000px;
    background:#fff;
}
#footer {
    background:#ccc;
    height:100px;
    bottom:0px;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div class="floating">floating footer</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Same script on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ce97999q/30/).

By the way there are several errors in your original script as:

- assigning events on `document` instead on `window`
- calculating `floatingFooter` outside of `stickyDiv()`
- wrong calculation of footer position, should use `offset()`

Comment: Why not add the clone in the html rather than making it in jquery

Comment: Because it would be duplicate content, which is not good for SEO.

Comment: You could just tell google not to crawl it, I think cloning it in jquery is a bit of an overkill

Comment: @[Huangism](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1058134/huangism), how would you tell google not to crawl the element on page, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
var div = $('.floating-div');
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var ftrOffsetTop = $('#footer').offset().top;

function stickyDiv() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((winHeight + scrollTop) >= ftrOffsetTop) {
        div.is(".fixed") && div.removeClass("fixed");
    } else {
        div.is(":not(.fixed)") && div.addClass("fixed");
    }
}

$(document).scroll(function () {
    stickyDiv();
});
```

```css
.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:1000;
}
.floating-div {
    background:#888;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.floating-div.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

#top {
    height:900px;
}
#wrapper {
    height:1000px;
    background:#fff;
}
#footer {
    background:#ccc;
    height:100px;
    bottom:0px;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div class="floating-div fixed">floating-div</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on what exactly you changed and why/how this works. This will help other readers learn instead of simply copying code :)

Comment: @DarkAshelin: absolutely :) I am a bit stuck at work and will surely add in details when I get my head back in here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
```

This should be declared inside the function, otherwise it will always return 0.

Edit: new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ce97999q/31/

It works like that but there is a much simpler way to do it.

Comment: While that's part of the problem, it does not solve the issue

Comment: In the fiddle that I linked, the div is placed on top of the footer when you hit the bottom. It just need some tweaking to be better but I guess the OP was stucked because of this.

Comment: How is that different from the OP's fiddle?

Comment: I just realized it worked only because I had dev tools opened (when I close it it doesn't work because the values are not the same). I'm gonna edit this.